# Undefined reference to mysqlx function in mysql connector

Tags: c++, mysql, linker, connector

I am trying to compile a c++ file, but the compiler seems to be missing some files for the mysql c++ connector. This is how I'm trying to compile it:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/boost_1_70_0 -L /usr/local/boost_1_70_0 -I /usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8 -pthread -std=c++2a `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` srv.cpp -o srv
```

One of the lines in the error message is

```
undefined reference to 
`mysqlx::abi2::r0::string::Impl::to_utf8[abi:cxx11] 
(mysqlx::abi2::r0::string const&)'
/tmp/ccf90UaW.o: In function `mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::DbDoc()'
```

It seems to be this file which tries to find some unlinked code:
`.../mysqlx/xdevapi.h`
Can someone point me in the right direction as to where the necessary files are? It seems like there are some important files that haven't been linked yet.

Comment: When building, the libraries to link with needs to be placed after any source or object files. So move the `pkg-config` invocation to the end of the command line.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but still the same error messages.

Comment: Where in that command have you linked the MySQL connector library?

Comment: [Here's the documentation for using the MySQL connector in C++](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-apps-general-considerations.html#connector-cpp-apps-dynamic-library)

Comment: I thought I only needed to tell the compiler where the headers were located

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm on linux, if that matters. I guess you can see that on the path names. Apologies for that

Answer (score 1):

Took me some time to figure this out. Managed to fix it by changing the makefile to this:

```
MYSQL_CONCPP_DIR = /usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8
BOOST_DIR = /usr/local/boost_1_70_0
CPPFLAGS = -I $(MYSQL_CONCPP_DIR) -L $(MYSQL_CONCPP_DIR) -I $(BOOST_DIR) -L 
$(BOOST_DIR)
LDLIBS = -lmysqlcppconn8 -lpthread
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
srv: srv.cpp
```